# Importing Data from excel to database in more time efficient way

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a excel file with 7-8 columns and 800-1200rows, That needs to be validated and inserted into database and what i have done is load the excel to a OleDB Datareader and read along the rows.The data are checked and validated and are loaded to datatable and then using  `SqlBulkCopy` they are written off to the server.

```
string ConnectionStr = string.Empty;

if (extension.ToUpper() == ".XLS")
{
   ConnectionStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/Cookies/BatchFile/" + FileName) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
}
else
{
   ConnectionStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/Cookies/BatchFile/" + FileName) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
}

DataTable Err = new DataTable();
dter.Columns.Add("MainCode", typeof(string));
dter.Columns.Add("Remarks", typeof(string));

DataTable DtASBAMaster = new DataTable();
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("ASBARef");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("ClientCode");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("BranchCode");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("ShareHolderAc");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("CyCode");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("AcType");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("DMATId");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("ClientId");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("BOId");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("BankCode");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("OpenDate");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("EnteredBy");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("ApprovedBy");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("Name");
DtASBAMaster.Columns.Add("ASBAStatus");

DataTable Dtimport = new DataTable();
Dtimport.Columns.Add("BatchNo");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("BranchCode");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("AcType");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("CyCode");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("MainCode");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("TranDate");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("NoOfShare");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("Name");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("BankCode");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("ThisBranch");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("RegNo");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("DMATId");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("ClientId");
Dtimport.Columns.Add("TakeCharge");

while (odr.Read())
{                       
   //Check values against next table to database -->Database trip 1
   SqlDataReader dr = DataAccess.ASBA.DA_Asba.GetMainCodeAsba(Session["ConnSTR"].ToString(), mainCode: MainCode);
   if (dr.Read())
   {
      //Perform Action if value are inseted in next table 
   }
   else
   {
      if (New == "T")
      {
         //Fetch Details from someother table in database to load in next table
         //add to datatable DtASBAMaster

        else {
                //Add to  datatable Err
                continue;
             }
      }

      //Calculation and stuffs 
      if (!GetBalance(MainCode, TotalAmount.ToString(), IsChargeASBA))
      {
         //Add to  datatable Err
      }
      else
      {
         if (!MainCodeProcessed.Add(MainCode))
         {
            dter.Rows.Add(MainCode, "Dublicate Maincode in the Batch");
            continue;
         }

         Dtimport.Rows.Add(BatchNo, BranchCode, AcType, CyCode, MainCode, SimpleHTTPModule.Today.ToString(), NoOfShare, Name, Session["BranchCodeSelected"].ToString(), Session["BranchCodeSelected"].ToString(), RegisterNo, Dmate, Clientid, IsChargeASBA);

    }

 }
 SqlTransaction myTrans = null;
 conn.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 myTrans = conn.BeginTransaction();
 cmd.Connection = conn;
 cmd.Transaction = myTrans;
 try {
       successcount = Dtimport.Rows.Count;
       if (successcount > 0)
       {
          string Qrystring = @"INSERT INTO ASBABatApplyTable(BatchNo,BranchCode,BatchDetails,IsPrinted,IsApproved,EnteredBy,CompanyCode,IsuuedDate,NoOfTrans) values(@BatchNo,@BranchCode,@BatchDetails,@IsPrinted,@IsApproved,@EnteredBy,@CompanyCode,@IsuuedDate,@NoOfTrans)";
          ////Qrystring = Qrystring + " VALUES('" + BatchNo + "','" + BatchDetails + "','F','F','" + EnteredBy + "')";

          cmd.CommandText = Qrystring;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNo", BatchNo);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchCode", Session["BranchCodeSelected"].ToString());//
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchDetails", txtBatchDesc.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsPrinted", "F");
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsApproved", "F");
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnteredBy", EnteredBy);//
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyCode", txtCompanyCode.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsuuedDate", SimpleHTTPModule.Today.ToShortDateString());//
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfTrans", successcount);//
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          //bulk copy
          SqlBulkCopy tblcpyASBAMaster= new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default,myTrans);
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("ASBARef", "ASBARef");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("ClientCode", "ClientCode");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("BranchCode", "BranchCode");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("ShareHolderAc", "ShareHolderAc");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("CyCode", "CyCode");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("AcType", "AcType");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("DMATId", "DMATId");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("ClientId", "ClientId");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("BOId", "BOId");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("BankCode", "BankCode");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("OpenDate", "OpenDate");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("EnteredBy", "EnteredBy");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("ApprovedBy", "ApprovedBy");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("ASBAStatus", "ASBAStatus");
          tblcpyASBAMaster.DestinationTableName = "ASBAMaster";
          tblcpyASBAMaster.WriteToServer(DtASBAMaster);

          SqlBulkCopy tblcpy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn,SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, myTrans);
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("BatchNo", "BatchNo");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("BranchCode", "BranchCode");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("AcType", "AcType");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("CyCode", "CyCode");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("MainCode", "MainCode");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("TranDate", "TranDate");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("NoOfShare", "NoOfShare");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("BankCode", "BankCode");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("ThisBranch", "ThisBranch");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("RegNo", "RegNo");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("DMATId", "DMATId");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("ClientId", "ClientId");
          tblcpy.ColumnMappings.Add("TakeCharge", "TakeCharge");
          tblcpy.DestinationTableName = "ASBABatApplyTran";
          tblcpy.WriteToServer(Dtimport);
          myTrans.Commit();
          Session["Imported"] = "IMPORTED :" + successcount + " Records";           
      }             
  }
```

Currently it takes about 12-15 minutes to load a excel and longer when the database uses is heavy.How can it be optimized to perform better?

P.S Feel free to roast on the coding conventions and practice with alternative/better way  to it and suggestion on where i am doing wrong. Thank you.

---

EDIT:
So after code analysis, i found 4  database trip for a single record and removed the ones that were unnecessary and moved up all the validation against database values to sql function to reduce the database trip down to 1. After that the importing have been relatively quicker.

Many Thanks to everyone invloved. :)

Comment: You should profile your code and determine exactly where the slowdown is occurring.

Comment: It looks as though you are opening a new SqlDataReader for every row in your Excel file (which BTW you don't appear to close?).  This will be hideously slow. Can you not read everything in at once and hold in memory (in a Dictionary???).  Very hard to tell though, as it is totally unclear from your code what the SqlDataReader is being used for.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, the SqlDataReader is to check if the record is present in another table or not and take a few data from that table  which are not supplied from the excel.

Comment: How many rows does this other table contain?  If it is not too many, you would be much quicker to read it all in to a DataTable once, which is then held in memory, and then use Select() with a filter for each step through the Excel file.

Comment: Currently 13K and increasing. Loading all into datatable would be slower i guess.